# Data Table in R from 3 Columns

Tags: r, data.table

How do I convert a data-set with 3 columns, for example:

```
 V1   V2   V3
 X    AB   6 
 X    EF   5
 Y    CD   7 
 Z    EF   8
 A    JK   9
 B    LM   10
 B    JK   6
```

To:

```
  AB CD EF JK LM
X 6  0  5  0  0
Y 0  7  0  0  0
Z 0  0  8  0  0 
A 0  0  0  9  0
B 0  0  0  6  10
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, V1~V2, fill=0, value.var="V3")
##   V1 AB CD EF JK LM
## 1  A  0  0  0  9  0
## 2  B  0  0  0  6 10
## 3  X  6  0  5  0  0
## 4  Y  0  7  0  0  0
## 5  Z  0  0  8  0  0
```

Or to get a matrix use

```
 acast(df, V1~V2, value.var='V3', fill=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per suggested by @akrun, you could use base R:

```
xtabs(V3~V1+V2, df)
```

Which gives:

```
#   V2
#V1  AB CD EF JK LM
#  A  0  0  0  9  0
#  B  0  0  0  6 10
#  X  6  0  5  0  0
#  Y  0  7  0  0  0
#  Z  0  0  8  0  0
```

Or using `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, V2, V3, fill = 0)
```

Which gives:

```
#  V1 AB CD EF JK LM
#1  A  0  0  0  9  0
#2  B  0  0  0  6 10
#3  X  6  0  5  0  0
#4  Y  0  7  0  0  0
#5  Z  0  0  8  0  0
```

---

**data**

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("AB", "CD", "EF", "JK", "LM"
), class = "factor"), V3 = c(6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```